# Keydown event: problems with '@'

Tags: jquery, keydown, ctrl

This is the problem: I need to intercept the char @, but with jQuery and keydown event I get only the code 17.

How can I get the real code (192) with the `property event.altKey = true`?

This is my code. It is connected to an input field:

```
$(this).keydown(function(e) {
   var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

   alert(e.keyCode + " - " + e.which + " - alt:" + e.altKey + " - shift:" + e.shiftKey + " - ctrl:" + e.ctrlKey);
});
```

This alert always shows 17 (ctrl / alt). How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplis? Is this an input field?

Comment: Because you're alerting (blocking) on `keydown` and therefore you won't register the second key.

Comment: yes, it is connected to an input field. but i don't know how to intercept the key i need '@'...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  http://jsbin.com/ohucuj/edit#preview

```
$(function() {
  $("#thingToTest").keydown(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 50) {
      $("#message").html("You pressed SHIFT+2 or @ !!!"); 
    }else{
      $("#message").html(e.keyCode + " - " + e.which + " - alt:" + e.altKey + " - shift:" + e.shiftKey + " - ctrl:" + e.ctrlKey);
    }
  });
});
```

Just test for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and the <kbd>2</kbd> key.

Comment: I'm on mac, and I use alt + 2.

Comment: I tested that with my mac, it works the same. Guess I don't use alt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what 192 id, but I found that `@` is nr 64.

You can capture that with *keypress* event like,

```
$("#textfield").keypress(function(e) 

if (e.which == 64)
{
    console.log('you typed "@" symbol!');
} 

});
```